# writing from STFT to audio using ISTFT adding harmonics to audio not present before

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, audio, python, stft

I'm doing quite a bit of the samething as I wrote in this post here :
[Shifting frequency peaks such that w[i] moves to w[i/n] using STFT and IFFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/93090/shifting-frequency-peaks-such-that-wi-moves-to-wi-n-using-stft-and-ifft)

I'll quote from it here to present the issue I now face which is different from the one in the post :

I am trying to do a kind of frequency compression on say 20 most energetic frequencies in a particular slice of a STFT. If w[i] is the frequency peak for a slice of STFT at a particular time, then I want to move w[i] to w[i/n] where n is arbitrary. To make sure invertability is still maintained I'm using a 2 sided STFT and just switch w[i] with w[i/n] and making sure that conjugate symmetry is still maintained. Here the n factor im shifting down by is 4.

I got over that problem by taking the complex values of the signal peaks of a double sided STFT and writing it to a new blank frequency representation such that the peak is transposed to a lower frequency i such that i -> i/n and again i use n as 4. I do this for every time slice of the STFT and create a new STFT and then I apply ISTFT to get a time domain signal.

Here's the code

```
fs = 10e4
N = 10e4
amp = 2 * np.sqrt(2)
noise_power = 0* fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
carrier = amp * np.sin(2*np.pi*3e4*time )
x = carrier
sf.write(r'C:\Users\aniru\OneDrive\Desktop\test.wav',x,int(fs))
print(len(x))
f, t, Zxx = signal.stft(x, fs, nperseg=500,return_onesided=False,window='hann')
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Zxx), vmin=0, vmax=amp, shading='gouraud')
plt.title('STFT Magnitude')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
Spectra= Zxx
reinserter = Zxx
Zxx= abs(Zxx)
#plt.plot(f,Zxx[:,100])
#plt.show()

print("Array Dimension = ",len(Spectra.shape))
newstft = []
print(len(t))
for q in range(0,len(t)):
    freqdic = {}
    fslice=Spectra[:,q]
    list = sorted(range(len(Zxx[:,q])), key=lambda i: Zxx[:,q][i])[-4:]
    p = np.zeros(len(fslice),dtype=complex)
    peaklist =list[::2]
    for i in peaklist:
        lowered = int(i/4)
        if lowered not in freqdic:
            freqdic[lowered] = 1
            p[lowered] = fslice[i]*10
            p[len(fslice)-lowered] =fslice[len(fslice)-i]*10
    newstft.append(p)

newstft = np.array(newstft)
newstft= np.transpose(newstft)
_, xrec = signal.istft(newstft, fs,input_onesided=False,nperseg=500)
sf.write(r'C:\Users\aniru\OneDrive\Desktop\testnew.wav',np.real(xrec),int(fs))
f, t, Zxx = signal.stft(np.real(xrec), fs, nperseg=500,return_onesided=False)
```

The STFT of the signal x I put in is as follows :

[image]

The STFT I get on the last line of the code is as follows, which is done after processing every time slice of if STFT, transposing the peaks onto a clean frequency map and then doing this for everytime slice and stitching it all together. I take an inverse of the new STFT labelled as such and clear out the tiny imaginary part by taking the real part and then pass it to STFT again to see what has happened. It seems to have worked out fine. This is STFT of the last line:

[image]

But after writing np.real(xrec) unto file and playing it, I hear it harsh and putting my phone's spectrograph app (spectroid) on it I see this [image]

Note: spectrograph of x is as you'd expect just a single flat line lasting a second.

Comment: I'm only seeing the negative frequency component of the sine wave, but shouldn't both the negative and positive frequencies be present?

Comment: @Baddioes I think the top half represents phase, i haven't labelled axis rightly, taking a time slice I see both negative and positive frequency present

Comment: I am not sure this is indeed the problem, but you may have issues with the continuity of your signal. You can double check that by plotting the reconstruction of two successive frames. Although out of my mind I think this shouldn’t be the case if you put energy into single bins it would be a good idea to test it.

Comment: @ZaellixA I looked at the time domain signal more closely, there doesn't seem to be any discontinuities but looking at the whole thing, it seems amplitude modulated ?! 

https://imgur.com/a/xCMo4QB

If it looks like amplitude modulated, I wonder then why it doesn't show up on the STFT as such, as I understand it AM would include the modulation frequency in addition to the carrier's which would be the peak.

Comment: This does look like beating… Are these results acquired with a single frequency component or you have more in the original spectrum?

Comment: @ZaellixA just a single frequency component, it's pretty bizzare and I'm stumped. The beating seems to be at a pretty low frequency too compared to the rest of the thing. That's another curiosity generated by this apart from the weird harmonics when writing the audio to file. The original signal x is a sinewave generated at the top of the code

Comment: Seems like such beats kind of things are also generated with griffin lim algorithm :
https://speechprocessingbook.aalto.fi/Modelling/griffinlim.html , but in that case the magnitude spectral is also different. Is there any STFT parameter I can change to see if I get a different looking mag spectra ?

Comment: It’s not clear to me whether your STFT algorithm uses any overlap. Furthermore, if seems you use a “Hann” window and I think you should check whether your window with the specified overlap (if any!) satisfies the COLA constraint. It seems you can use [```scipy.signal.check_COLA```](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.check_COLA.html) to check whether your windowing scheme (with overlap) satisfies the constraint. If not, then I believe this is your problem. It seems that you may get additional frequencies due to discontinuities in the reconstruction.

Comment: @ZaellixA seeing this now again, I had given up for a while and it looks like it's not resolved. I tried the COLA thing and turns out the window I was using along with the overlap indeed did not satisfy the COLA constraint, I replaced it with one that does and I am still getting those pesky harmonics for some reason

Comment: I’ll try your code myself to see what I get and let you know as soon as I have something